# Download intraday historical stock data

Tags: python, pandas, download

I want to download historical intraday stock data. I've found AlphaVantage offers two years of data. It's the longest history of data that I've found for free.

I'm making a script to download the full two years of data for all ticker symbols that they offer and in all timeframes. They provide the data divided in 30 days intervals from the current day (or the last trading day, I'm not sure). The rows go from newest to oldest timedate. I want to reverse the order in which the data appears and concatenate all the months with the column headers appearing only once. So I would have a single `csv` file with two years of data for each stock and timeframe. The rows of the data would go from oldest to newest timedate.

The problem I have is that I also want to use the script to update the data and I don't know how to append only the data that doesn't already appear in my files. The data that I've downloaded goes from `2020-09-28 07:15:00` to `2020-10-26 20:00:00` in 15 minutes intervals (when they exists, there are some missing). When I use the script again I'd like to update the data. I'd like to delete somehow the rows that already appear and append only the rest. So if the last datetime that appears is for example `2020-10-26 20:00:00` it would continue appending from `2020-10-26 2020-10-26 20:15:00` if it exists. How can I update the data correctly?

Also, when updating, if the file already exists, it copies the column headers which is something I don't want to do. Edit: I've solved this with `header=(not os.path.exists(file))` but it seems very inefficient to check if the file exists in every iteration.

I also have to make the script comply with the API's rule of 5 calls per minute and 500 calls per day. Is there a way for the script to stop when it reaches the daily limit and continue at that point next time it runs? Or should I just add a 173 seconds sleep between API calls?

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

from typing import List
from requests import get
from pathlib import Path
import os.path
import sys

BASE_URL= 'https://www.alphavantage.co/'


def download_previous_data(
    file: str,
    ticker: str,
    timeframe: str,
    slices: List,
):
    for _slice in slices:
        url = f'{BASE_URL}query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY_EXTENDED&symbol={ticker}&interval={timeframe}&slice={_slice}&apikey=demo&datatype=csv'
        pd.read_csv(url).iloc[::-1].to_csv(file, mode='a', index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')


def main():

    # Get a list of all ticker symbols
    print('Downloading ticker symbols:')
    #df = pd.read_csv('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=LISTING_STATUS&apikey=demo')
    #tickers = df['symbol'].tolist()
    tickers = ['IBM']

    timeframes = ['1min', '5min', '15min', '30min', '60min']

    # To download the data in a subdirectory where the script is located
    modpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))

    # Make sure the download folders exists
    for timeframe in timeframes:
        download_path = f'{modpath}/{timeframe}'
        #download_path = f'/media/user/Portable Drive/Trading/data/{timeframe}'
        Path(download_path).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    # For each ticker symbol download all data available for each timeframe
    # except for the last month which would be incomplete.
    # Each download iteration has to be in a 'try except' in case the ticker symbol isn't available on alphavantage
    for ticker in tickers:
        print(f'Downloading data for {ticker}...')
        for timeframe in timeframes:
            download_path = f'{modpath}/{timeframe}'
            filepath = f'{download_path}/{ticker}.csv'

            # NOTE:
            # To ensure optimal API response speed, the trailing 2 years of intraday data is evenly divided into 24 "slices" - year1month1, year1month2,
            # year1month3, ..., year1month11, year1month12, year2month1, year2month2, year2month3, ..., year2month11, year2month12.
            # Each slice is a 30-day window, with year1month1 being the most recent and year2month12 being the farthest from today.
            # By default, slice=year1month1

            if Path(filepath).is_file():  # if the file already exists
                # download the previous to last month
                slices = ['year1month2']
                download_previous_data(filepath, ticker, timeframe, slices)
            else:  # if the file doesn't exist
                # download the two previous years
                #slices = ['year2month12', 'year2month11', 'year2month10', 'year2month9', 'year2month8', 'year2month7', 'year2month6', 'year2month5', 'year2month4', 'year2month3', 'year2month2', 'year2month1', 'year1month12', 'year1month11', 'year1month10', 'year1month9', 'year1month8', 'year1month7', 'year1month6', 'year1month5', 'year1month4', 'year1month3', 'year1month2']
                slices = ['year1month2']
                download_previous_data(filepath, ticker, timeframe, slices)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an awful lot of questions within your question!
These are suggestions for you to try, but I have no way to test the validity of them:

1. Read all your files names into a list check files names exist against the list rather than pinging the os each time
2. Read the data from existing file and append everything in pandas and write new file. Can't tell if you are appending the csv files but if you're having difficulty there just read the data and append new data - until you figure out how to append a excel correctly. Or save new iterations to their own file and consolidate files later.
3. Look into drop_duplicates() if you have concerned with having duplicates
4. Look into time module for time.sleep() in your for loops for reduce calls
5. If you have 1min data you can look into resample() to 5min, 15min rather than importing at all those timeframes